# Javascript setInterval function doesn't stop

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I am checking a time period from my database and showing how much time left to the end of the period.

I got the time value with `strtotime` as a variable `$lefttime` in php. My problem is with javascript part so i am not writing the php codes.

So my javascript code is:

```
var s = <?php echo $lefttime; ?>; //s stands for seconds
var d = Math.floor(s/60);         //d stands for minutes
s -= d*60;

var count = setInterval(functime, 1000);
    function functime() {
        s--;

        if(s < 0) {
            d--;
            s = 59;                 
            var san = s;
            var dak = "0" + d;   
        }
        else if(d < 0 ) {
                clearInterval(functime);
                document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = "over";
            }
        else if(d < 10){
            var dak = "0" + d;
            if(s < 10) { 
                       var san = "0" + s;
                    }
            else { 
                       var san = s; 
                    }
        }
        else if(s < 10){
            var san = "0" + s;
            if(d < 10) { 
                       var dak = "0" + d;
                    }
            else { 
                       var dak = d; 
                    }
        }
        else { 
            var san = s;
            var dak = d;
        }

        document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = dak+":"+san;
    }
```

*I create `dak` and `san` variables to check if the value is a digit, if so add `0` to the left of them.*

So it works perfect except stopping when `d < 0`. It counts down till `00:00` and then shows 
`0-1:59`, and then `undefined:undefined`.

Please help me I can't find what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setInterval returns an identifier for the interval

```
var myInterval = setInterval(functime, 1000);
```

And it's this numeric identifier that should be passed as a parameter to clearInterval

```
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

update: You code is much too complex. You have too many nested if/else, so it makes it complicated to understand. You should create several simple functions to isolate small chunks of code with a specific responsibility. By example:

```
var s = <?php echo $lefttime; ?>; //s stands for seconds
var d = Math.floor(s/60);         //d stands for minutes
s -= d * 60;

update(d, s);
if(d >= 0) {
    var myInterval = setInterval(functime, 1000);
} 
else {
    finish();
}

function functime() {
    s--;
    if(s < 0 ) {
        d--;
        if (d < 0 ) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            finish();
            return;
        }
        else {
            s = 59;
        }
    }
    update(d, s);   
}

function format(value) {
    if(value < 10) {
        return '0' + value;
    }
    return value;
}

function update(d, s) {
    var san = format(s);
    var dak = format(d);
    document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = dak + ":" + san;
}

function finish() {
    document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = "over";
}
```

Comment: Tried. but still having same problem

Comment: You probably have another problem in your code. But I assure you your code is wrong on this specific point.

Comment: Now the second keeps counting down like '00:0-1' and '00:0-2'

Comment: should be ok now. Try to make your code simpler and mode structured, it will easier to debug.

Comment: Yes, like Pascal says, you've stored your interval reference in a variable called "count" and then your trying to clear "functime", which is the name of a function, not anything to do with your setTimeout id. SetInterval doesn't return a count, so that's not a good variable name.

Comment: Thanks for your great work. Now with your last update; it prints "over" after 00:00. But when the page was refreshed it keeps counting like 0-1:50 and when reaches to 0-1:00 it prints "over" again. But not keeps after page reloaded. :(

Comment: the javascript is executed from start on each page load. If you want to keep state between page loadings, you have to send the state to the server, and generate a different page.

Comment: @PascalLeMerrer  I fixed this. you can update your answer like this:

I added

`if (d < 0 ) {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            document.getElementById('birrek').innerHTML = "over";
            return; // avoids the final call to update()
        }
else {`

after this: 

`var myInterval = setInterval(functime, 1000);`

Comment: I did it, but I avoided code duplication. And return is useless in the case.